# How to render a lottie animation to fullscreen or full container width

Tags: html, css, canvas, lottie

First time working with lottie animation, I'm using the lottie web library from [here](http://airbnb.io/lottie/#/web), but I can't find any information about how display the animation fullscreen or the same width of the container.

```js
lottie.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById("lottiesContainer"), // the dom element
  renderer: "svg",
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
});
```

```css
#lottiesContainer {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lottie-web/5.7.13/lottie.min.js"></script>
<div id="lottiesContainer">
  <div style="width: 1140px; height: auto" class="lottie schedinaBackground" data-animation-path="https://assets8.lottiefiles.com/private_files/lf30_jgz3zuii.json" data-anim-loop="true" data-name="schedinaBackground"></div>
</div>
```

working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Decagrog/x49ftq3o/2/)

In the example I've a div column of 1140px width that contains the lottie.
I tried to simply give 100% or 1140px width to the lottie div but the behavior is not what I expected, actual lottie size is about 1/3, can't even say exactly because the lottie is rendered into a canvas which prevents the use of the inspector

[image]

Comment: You have the renderer set to 'svg' so the created animation will try to take up all available space unless you set height/width. Trying removing all height/width from your HTML and CSS

Comment: I tried to remove width and height set in css but the lottie dimension is still the same